# Warped text on Windows 10

Tags: windows, gpu, amd-radeon

I'm having this weird issue with my GPU (MSI Armor OC RX480 4GB). The text sometimes just warps (sorry if this is not the appropriate term, English is not my main language) on the screen. Nothing happens while gaming, no artifacts or "text warping" whatsoever. Ran Furmark for a few minutes with no errors also. Ran DDU and reinstalled drivers as well. Any ideas?

[image: Text warping]

Comment: While it many not be, this looks like a slight crack on your LCD panel.

Comment: The panel is fine, for example Furmark does not show any errors on that part of the screen. Thanks for the feedback.